# Screen gets darker when renaming a file or googling

Tags: display, brightness

Lately, I have been having the following problem:
My screen gets darker every time

- I try to rename a file or folder (any computer files or in browsers, google drive files, anywhere)
- I search for something on Google/Yandex and similar sites
- Pop-up windows or boxes show up in the foreground
- probably more cases.
  After I finish renaming/close pop-up windows, it becomes normal.
  This DOES bother me and hurt my eyes.
  I don't understand why so, all auto-brightness, adaptable options are turned off. Tried solutions to similar problems, but doesn't help. What could be the problem and the solution? Thank you.

OS: Windows 10, Graphics Card: Intel

Comment: Does it happen immediately or fade over time? What's your graphics card?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: It both dims and brightens within 2-3 seconds. Intel, Windows 10.